# VS ¿Cómo puedo leer de manera parcial un arhivo .txt y mostrarlo en un textbox?

Tags: visual-studio-2019

Estoy intentando hacer que una parte en especifico de un arhivo .txt como en el ejemplo de abajo se muestre en un textbox.

```
Hola!
Esto es un texto de prueba
---
Encabezado 1
---
Nombres:
Apellidos:
... (Varias lineas seguidas)
Dirección:
---
Encabezado 2 
---
Lugar:
Fecha:
... (Varias lineas seguidas)
Referencia:
---
Encabezado 3
---
...
```

Es decir desde la línea que dice "encabezado 1" seguido de un numero n líneas se muestre hasta que empiece "encabezado 2", de esta manera podría presentar solo lo que dice cada encabezado al elegir dicha opción en un combo box.

Lo poco que se me ocurrio fue esta pequeña porcion de codigo.

```
Imports System.IO
Dim ListaEncabezado As String
Private Sub Combo_box1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Combo_box1.SelectedIndexChanged
        If (Combo_box1.SelectedItem = "Encabezado 1") Then
            ListaEncabezado = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(Application.StartupPath + "\Texto.txt")
            If ListONU = "Encabezado 1" Then
            
            (??)

            End If
        End If
```

Espero alguien pueda ayudarme, el programa lo estoy haciendo en Visual Studio 2019, de antemano muchas gracias por la atención.

Comment: Prueba con [`IndexOf()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=net-5.0) y [`Substring()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-5.0)

Answer (score 0):

A ver si te sirve

He confeccionado el siguiente ejemplo para éste archivo de texto:

```
Nombres:
    Roberto
    María
    Eduardo
    Geremías

Apellidos:
    Díaz Suárez
    Morán Queipo
    Suárez Fernández
    Fernández Fernández

Localidades:
    Laviana
    Sotrondio
    El entrego
    La Felguera

...........
```

El código sería el siguiente:

```
//al hacer click en el botón
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        //recorremos el archivo por filas 
        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\\Users\\usuario\\Documentos\\Text\\texto.txt");
        //si la fila no es nula, o sea, si tiene texto
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            //si la línea coincide con el índice, en esta caso "Nombres:", fíjate que incluye los dos puntos
            if (line.Equals("Nombres:")) {
                //saltamos a la siguiente línea, en mi caso cogería su valor "Roberto"
                line = file.ReadLine();
                //mientras la línea no esté vacía
                while (!line.Equals(""))
                {
                    //agrega el contenido al combo 1
                    comboBox1.Items.Add(line);
                    //saltamos a la siguiente línea
                    line = file.ReadLine();
                }
            }
        }
        //creamos un segundo bloque igual al primero para el segundo combo renombrando file y line con un 2 al final
        string line2;
        System.IO.StreamReader file2 = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\\Users\\eltra\\OneDrive\\Documentos\\Text\\texto.txt");
        while ((line2 = file2.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            //buscamos el siguiente valor del índice, en éste caso "Apellidos:"
            if (line2.Equals("Apellidos:"))
            {
                //tomamos el valor de la siguiente línea a "Apellidos:"
                line2 = file2.ReadLine();
                while (!line2.Equals(""))
                {
                    comboBox2.Items.Add(line2);
                    line2 = file2.ReadLine();
                }
            }
        }
        //lo mismo para el tercero
        string line3;
        System.IO.StreamReader file3 = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\\Users\\eltra\\OneDrive\\Documentos\\Text\\texto.txt");
        while ((line3 = file3.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (line3.Equals("Localidades:"))
            {
                line3 = file3.ReadLine();
                while (!line3.Equals(""))
                {
                    comboBox3.Items.Add(line3);
                    line3 = file3.ReadLine();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Tienes que tener en cuenta que mi código se interrumpe con una línea en blanco, o sea, que al final del fichero de texto deberías de terner una línea en blanco o te arrojaría un error

Comment: ¿No era en Visual Basic?

Comment: Eh tomado algunas ideas del código  de "el.trasgu" para seguir en la elaboración de mi trabajo y sí era en Visual Studio, algo adicional es que buscaba que detecte una sección y muestre lo que se encontraba bajo la misma, no agregar los ítems debajo de la sección al combo box, aun así agradezco el tiempo dedicado.